# Nested pgfmath functions give wrong value

Tags: pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I am trying to have a "base" common implementation of two pgfmath functions defined via `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` which vary only by one number.  I have successfully done so and when I print the results *within the inner function/common implementation*, everything works fine.  My problem is I can't seem to get the value out via `\pgfmathresult`.

I have tried `\pgfmathparse`, `\pgfmathsetmacro` and setting `\pgfmathresult` directly via `\edef`.  Nothing seems to work.  I know `\pgfmathresult` is reused for a lot of computations inside pgf, but I thought my usage was "safe" in the sense that I "smuggle" the value out and I use it right after.

Is it that what I am trying to do is not supported at all ?

Here is a minimal working example which has the same behavior (my actual function as much more code) my problem.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fn_impl}{...}{%
\begingroup%
   \pgfmathparse{12.0}\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult%
\endgroup%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fn}{...}{%
\begingroup%
   \pgfmathparse{fn_impl(#1)}\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult%
\endgroup%
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Simply parsing value:~\pgfmathparse{12.0}\pgfmathresult%

Calling fn(1.3,3.0,1.5):~\pgfmathparse{fn(1.3,3.0,1.5)}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

The code outputs:

> Simply parsing value: 12.0

> Calling fn(1.3,3.0,1.5): 1.5

But I would expect:

> Simply parsing value: 12.0

> Calling fn(1.3,3.0,1.5): 12.0

What part of my understanding is wrong.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: A better approach than forwarding the arguments as another `pgfmath` function's arguments would be to have a single internal *macro* that expects the arguments in the `...` notation, so that you don't have to do those tricks with unbracing and adding commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the way PGF forwards the `...` argument specification to the underlying macro. If you hand in only a single argument you'll get it as is, if you pass it multiple arguments you'll get a list in the form `{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}...`, but this doesn't work if you forward it directly to the next `pgfmath` function. Instead you'd have to unwrap the arguments and pass them in comma separated.

The following does that using `expl3` (this might fail if one of the args need to be wrapped in braces):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fn_impl}{...}{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmathparse{12.0}\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fn}{...}{%
  \begingroup%
    \forwarddotargs{fn_impl}{#1}% <- calls pgfmathparse
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \forwarddotargs #1#2
  {%
    \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#2}
      {
        \__ghleci_forwarddotargs_auxi:en
          { \tl_map_tokens:nn {#2} { , \exp_not:n } }
          {#1}
      }
      { \pgfmathparse { #1 (#2) } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__ghleci_forwarddotargs_auxi:nn #1
  { \__ghleci_forwarddotargs_auxii:on { \use_none:n #1 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ghleci_forwarddotargs_auxi:nn { e }
\cs_new:Npn \__ghleci_forwarddotargs_auxii:nn #1#2
  { \pgfmathparse { #2 (#1) } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ghleci_forwarddotargs_auxii:nn { o }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Simply parsing value:~\pgfmathparse{12.0}\pgfmathresult%

Calling fn(1.3,3.0,1.5):~\pgfmathparse{fn(1.3,3.0,1.5)}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no choice but to accept that this might be my problem, since your solution works, but I fail to see how it relates to the problem.  Especially since I was able to get the parameter values in my inner function in my tests. :-(

Could you explain why the \use_none:n is required?  I am reading the documentation (interface3.pdf), but can't understand it.

I have also tried with a non pgf macro, but was unable to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: @ghlecl the `\use_none:n` removes the first comma. I build the argument by looping over every item in the `{arg_1}...{arg_n}` list leaving `, arg_i` for every argument. Hence after the first step I'd get `, arg_1, ..., arg_n` (without the spaces). As to why PGF fails here: No idea, I find the design decisions of the `...` arguments strange, tbh. And I have no idea why `fn_impl({arg1}{arg2}{arg3})` doesn't result in the `\pgfmathresult` being what you smuggled.